# Intento usar un border-top-width en los <li> de mi pagina web y no me andan

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero conseguir que los li se separen de la parte superior de la pagina y que se queden en el borde inferior del div, intente de todo para que se separe y no me estaria andando, el objetivo es el que ya mencione y que no tengan borde los li, cosa que intente con un border:hidden; pero parece que se quedan sin borde y no me deja verlo.

Les dejo el css:

```
body{
    margin:0px;

}

#topbardiv{
    background-color:rgb(223, 210, 226)
}

#menu{
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding:55px;
    border:30px;
    margin:0;
}

#menu li{
    display: inline;
    border:solid;
    border-width:4px;
    border-top-width: 130px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

El html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="howliescss.css"> 

        <title>
            Howlies
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="topbardiv">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>Inicio</li>
                <li>Accesorios</li>
                <li>Comida</li>        <!--Marcadores-->
                <li>Howlies</li>
                <li>Ofertas</li>
                <li>Informacion</li>
                <li>Cuenta</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
       
    


</html>
```

Comment: Agrega tu HTML por favor

Comment: Ahi lo puse, tendria que salirte

Comment: Con eso estás haciendo el borde más grande, si quieres despegar el menú del parte superior ajusta los márgenes xD.

Comment: Ahi intente agregando un margin-top y tampoco me sirve :(

Comment: @Ramita ¿tu objetivo es que todo el contenedor `<ul>` quede por debajo del `<div id="topbardiv">`?. De ser así ¿los bordes negros deben mantenerse?.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/tj9ym1
Asi es como quiero que quede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te hago en esta respuesta una propuesta para construirla usando flexbox, por que:

- Podemos indicar de forma mas simple donde queremos que de dispongan los elementos

  - Esto nos ayudará para mover en el eje y al menú al final
  - Y también nos ayudaría a mover de forma mas simple al menú al centro en el eje x

Ya que al momento con lo que observo (y mi poca experiencia) sería indicarle con un posicionamiento que se quede al fondo o también indicarle que el margen inferior entre el menú y su contenedor padre sea de 0 y que los margenes izquierdo, derecho y superior si tengan una medida

- Posterior al contenedor principal donde estará incrustado el menú un color y un alto definido
- A la etiqueta `ul` le damos en su propiedad `display` el valor de flex

  - Con esto podemos mover a los elementos al final del eje y con `align-items`
  - Y con `justify-content` desplazamos a los elementos al centro
- Le damos un height de 100% para que cubra el alto de su contenedor padre
- Al final le damos estilos a los elementos `li`

Código:

```
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .menu {
        background-color: teal;
        height: 100px;
      }
      .menu-contenedor-listado {
        align-items: flex-end;
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .menu-contenedor-listado__elemento {
        border: 1px solid;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        width: 200px;
      }
    </style>
    <section class="menu">
      <nav class="menu-contenedor">
        <ul class="menu-contenedor-listado">
          <li class="menu-contenedor-listado__elemento">1</li>
          <li class="menu-contenedor-listado__elemento">2</li>
          <li class="menu-contenedor-listado__elemento">3</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
```

Viéndose así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! ahi me sirvio :)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba quitando del CSS #menu li
Las propiedades de padding y border-top-width y así te aparecerá el menú despegado del inicio se la página

```
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  /* border-top-width: 130px;*/
  /*padding: 20px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo tu problema es el siguiente el la declaracion de css, tus elementos li, tienen propiedad display:inline, estos elementos no tienen margen superior ni inferior por mas que los declares, cambia la propiedad display a inline-block, de esa manera puedes aplicarle el margen que desees.